# Why are my tomato plant leaves curling

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, leaves, tomatoes

I’ve got several tomato plants. They are all in large containers, watered regularly and given tomato feed every 2 weeks

All of the leaves are starting to curl as seen in the pictures below.

Does anyone have any thought on what could be causing this or what I can do to fix it?

[image: Photo 1]
[image: Photo 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually a sign that it needs more water. It can be that due to the weather the plants suddenly need more water than usual, or they want more water because the plants are bigger than before.

The plants look further healthy! A lot of unripe tomatoes already, and new flowers. Good luck!